# Multidimensional Array in hidden field

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a form that i'm attempting to pass values over via hidden fields. At the moment I pass over an ID and a quantity, they get sent in two separate arrays. I would like to send both of these in the same multidimensional array in one hidden field, is this possible?

Here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {

    foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $id => $value) {

        $ids .= $id . ',';

        $count += $value['quantity'];

        $totalPrice += $value['price'] * $value['quantity'];

    } 

    $query = $database->find_item_db($ids);

    foreach ($query as $single_query) {

    $id = $single_query['Sweet_ID'];

    $stock_level = $database->get_stock($id);

    $stock_quantity = (int)$stock_level[0]['Quantity'];

    echo $single_query['Description']; ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'] . '<a href="?idToRemove=' . $id . '&action=remove"> Remove </a>' . '</br>'; ?>

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="sweetids[][]"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $stock_quantity;?>" name="quantites[]"/>
```

Comment: You could send it through as a `json` string representation (`json_encode`),  setting the one `hidden` field as the json but I fail to see the reason behind this approach .. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Pogrindis I want to pass the data over so when a button is clicked I can then use those values to edit the database with PHP

Comment: Can you add an example for the array structure you want to pass through your form ?

Comment: Don't pass values via hidden fields - store them in session instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would send them via the hidden fields as arrays and then use the MultipleIterator class to group them in their own individual arrays.

Possibly something like this.

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator ();
$iterator->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($_POST['sweetids']));
$iterator->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($_POST['quantites']));
$iterator->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($_POST['stock']));

foreach ($iterator as $item)
{
    $id = $item[0];

    $quantity = (int)$item[1];

    $stock = (int)$item[2];

    $new_stock =  $stock - $quantity;

    $database->update_stock($id, $new_stock);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to serialize the array and just echo in into the hidden field

```
<textarea name="name" style="display:none;"/>
<?php echo serialize($data); ?>
</textarea>
```

And later undo with

```
unserialize($data);
```

After unserialize you got your array back as it was before

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 2 inputs for each of the sweets at the moment, it might be better to create a sweet collection and then use this as the value of the input.

Something along the following lines.

```
$sweetCollection = array();

foreach ($query as $single_query) {
   $sweet = array();
   // Set values
   $sweet['id'] = $single_query['Sweet_ID'];
   $sweet['level'] = $database->get_stock($sweet['id']);
   $sweet['quantity'] =  (int)$sweet['level'][0]['Quantity'];
   // Add to array 
   array_push($sweetCollection, $sweet);
   echo $single_query['Description']; ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'] . '<a href="?idToRemove=' . $id . '&action=remove"> Remove </a>' . '</br>'; ?>

}
```

Now when we want to add the input field we do as follows using `JSON`:

```
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo json_encode($sweetCollection); ?>" name="sweetCollection"/>
```

I'm not sure why you need this, as you could just use the `$_Input['name']` vars as usual though. Also the `JSON` string could become quite large and would be rather strange.